# Compare two files and extract values that you don't include in common to a third file

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

Basically I need to compare in the first room the file A that has 100 records (all of them numerical) and a file B that also has records (numerical). The idea is, to compare both files and generate a third party that gives me as an output, the numbers that are not Sundays both in file A and in B. That is if I compare A with B and the numbers that B has are not inside from A I generated a C file with those numbers that are not in common.

Example File A:

```
334030004141665
334030227891112
334030870429938
334030870429939
334030241924239
334030870429932
334030870429933
334030870429930
334030870429931
334030870429936
334030013091432
334030030028092
334030218459802
334030003074203
334030010435534
334030870429937
334030870429934
334030870429935
334030062679707
334030062679706
```

Example File B

```
334030013091432
334030030028092
334030218459802
334030003074203
334030010435534
334030010781511
334030010783039
334030204710123
334030203456292
334030203292057
334030010807268
334030010455298
334030240658153
334030218450890
334030023035316
334030010807456
334030010457538
334030071689268
334030204710136
```

Excpected File C

```
334030013091432
334030030028092
334030218459802
334030003074203
334030010435534
```

I have already tried with comm, diff, grep but nothing makes me work. The ideal would not be to sort the files, since these that I want to compare only have 100 records, but for the next one there will be more than one million records.

Thank you for your contributions.

Comment: Please, post some  sample data with the expected output and something you  have tried. Will both A and B have a million records or just A?

Comment: Hello James, thank you for your observations, I put some examples for A B and C file. And yes, both files have a million of records. Thank you. I expect that, when File B compares with the File A, the result in File C be only the records that are not presentend in File A.

Comment: C looks like the list of common lines. Can you please clarify _the numbers that are not Sundays both in file A and in B_

Comment: I need extract the common information in both files. TY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to look through my fingers with *I have already tried with comm, diff, grep* this time, but next time post some actual trials.

To *extract the common information in both files* the obvious would be to use `grep` for it:

```
$ grep -f A B
```

Output:

```
334030013091432
334030030028092
334030218459802
334030003074203
334030010435534
```

but `grep` in that form would accept partial matches as well, so being lazy I wouldn't see the `man grep` (well, I did, it's `grep -w -f A B`) but use awk instead:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}($0 in a)' A B
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {      # process the first file in the list
    a[$0]      # hash record to a hash
    next       # move to next record in the first file
}              # after this point process all the files after the first
($0 in a)      # if record found in a hash, output it
' A B          # put the smaller file first as it is stored in memory
```

Once you get to the million lines part, please time (`time grep ...` and `time awk ...`) the difference of both solutions and post in the comments.

Comment: Given that those are strings, not pattern, using `grep -F` should speed up the process. With 1M records in each file, awk (with n log(n) complexity), should be much faster than grep (n^2 complexity).

Comment: awk is probably complexity of _n_ as complexity of hash, I'd assume, is constant.

Comment: To mark that the record was in the first file, should the 'a[$0]' be 'a[$0] = 1' ?. The code implies looking for  a[$0] will create a key in 'a'. I see code is working, but I could not find reference in the info page for this behavior

Comment: I found a reference to this behavior: http://kirste.userpage.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_12.html#SEC114 Referencing non existing key will set it's value to NULL. This is defined as 'unfortunate'  (=backward compatibility hard to change) - a bug that has become a feature. I think very few users of awk knows about this

Comment: Sorry, I misread you at first, but yeah. Thanks for the link, I need to check it out.

Comment: I thought this is gawk behavior. However, it is also in the POSIX spec: `The application shall ensure that a multi-dimensioned index used with the in operator is parenthesized. The in operator, which tests for the existence of a particular array element, shall not cause that element to exist. Any other reference to a nonexistent array element shall automatically create it.` https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ Good learning experience

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am executing the command. At the end I will tell you the result. In case I now need those that are not common would I use '! ='?

For example

$ awk 'NR! = FNR {a [$ 0]; next} ($ 0 in a)' A B

Thank you.

Comment: If you need the ones that are in `B` but not in `A`, use `!($0 in a)` (or `($0 in a==0)` like people hate me doing :) instead of `($0 in a)`. If you need uncommon in both, that's a bit more complicated.